# Searching for a key in a trie returning null pointer exceptions

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, trie

I'm trying to create an insert method for a trie in Java, where the method takes a string as an input, and checks to see if a node for each letter exists in the trie: I've attempted this once with a simple Array, and once with a HashMap as seen here:

Array Approach

```
// Simple Array approach
public class trieNode {
    char value = '\n';
    final static int ALPHA_SIZE = 26;
    int count = 0;
    trieNode[] children = new trieNode[ALPHA_SIZE];
    boolean isEnd = false; //signifies the end of a word
    static trieNode root;
    trieNode parent;

    //constructor for the class
        trieNode(){
        for(int i = 0; i < ALPHA_SIZE; i++) {
            children[i] = null; 
        }
        }


        //add a node to the trie.
        static void trieInsert(String word) {

            trieNode search = root;
            for( int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                int index = word.charAt(i) - 'a'; //There doesn't seem to be any problem here, for example when the given char is c, index returns 2.

                if(word.charAt(i) == search.children[index].value) { //WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
                    search.children[index].count++;
                    search.children[index].isEnd = false;
                    search.children[index] = new trieNode();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(word + " has been added successfully to the trie.");
        }
```

HashMap Approach:

```
public class TrieNode {
    final static int ALPHABET_SIZE = 26;
    char value;
    boolean isEndOfWord;
    boolean isTrieLeaf;
    HashMap<Character, TrieNode> children = new HashMap();
    int count = 0;
    TrieNode root;
    TrieNode parent;


    TrieNode(){

    }

    void trieInsert(String word) {
        TrieNode search = root;
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if(search.children.containsKey(word.charAt(i))) {  //WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
                search.children.get(word.charAt(i)).count++; //increase the count by one.
                search = search.children.get(word.charAt(i)); //this character must already be in the trie, check the rest of the word
            }
            else {
                search.children.put(word.charAt(i), new TrieNode()); //create a new node in the map for the character.
                search = search.children.get(word.charAt(i)); //move to the newly created node and start the process again.

                search.children.get(word.charAt(i)).count++; //update the base variables for the Trie.
                search.children.get(word.charAt(i)).isEndOfWord = false;
            }

                if((word.length()-i) == 1)
                    search.children.get(word.charAt(i)).isTrieLeaf = true; //if it's the last word in the trie, change that value to true.
        }

    }

}
```

The problem occurs when I test them (ex trieInsert("cat")), I always get a null pointer exception at each if statement, but I was under the assumption that you could use null as a comparison in this manner, and you could set objects equal to null in this case?

Example Test

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TrieNode Trie = new TrieNode();

        Trie.trieInsert("cat");

    }

}
```

Am I missing something, and if so what can I do to fix it.

Comment: *"Am I missing something"* Debugging your code. [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149)

Comment: You never assign anything to `root`, so it is always `null`, which means that `search` is null, so `search.children` throws NullPointerException. Why is this surprising you?

Comment: My bad, it was under the implication that an object of that class was created, I added an example.

Comment: Objects of a class are created when you use the `new` operator. Values of fields and local variables are set when you assign something to it. Let me repeat my previous comment: **You never *assign* anything to `root`, so it is always `null`.** Calling `new` does not magically assign the reference to the new object anywhere. It is only assigned to fields/variables when *you* do it, e.g. like how your new example immediately assigns the new reference value to local variable `Trie`.

Comment: I'm aware that the root is assigned to null, that's what I expected. I'm checking to see if that is empty by comparing it to null. What I need to know is how can I check to see if it's empty without causing a null pointer exception?

Comment: I'm sorry, but *where* are you comparing `root` (or `search` to null)? Seems my eyes are failing me, because I can't find *any* code comparing them to null. Actually, the keyword `null` is only use **once** in the code, and that's in an assignment statement, so your *"comparing it to null"* claim is very much a figment of your imagination.